# Excel turn a string into a datetime object and keep formatting

Tags: excel

I have a datetime string:

```
20221025133811 which is -> year month day hour minutes seconds
```

I want to paste it into an excel cell and make it a date-time object so that
I can subtract it from another date-time.  I also want to keep it in the cell as 20221025133811.
I tried formatting the cell as 'Custom' and yyyymmddhhmmss but it doesn't work.  How to do this?

Comment: try custom format as `0000\/00\/00 00\:00\:00` but custom formatting should not be a right thing to do instead use a formula `=--TEXT(A2,"0000\/00\/00 00\:00\:00")`

Comment: So using the above formula you can then easily do the subtraction as well, `=(TEXT(B2,"0000\/00\/00 00\:00\:00")+0)-(TEXT(A2,"0000\/00\/00 00\:00\:00")+0)`  assuming `B2` is End date-time while `A2` is Start date-time

Comment: Look at this query : [Dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74196125/subtracting-two-dates-in-excel)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to add 1 column with the following formula:

```
=1*TEXT(@PrevColumnOrCellRef,"0000-00-00 00\:00\:00")
```

[image]