# Subtracting two dates in Excel

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula, ms-office

I would like to subtract two dates, the birth date, and the study date, and store the difference in terms of months. The DICOM entries have a weird format for the birth date (e.g.,19760404) and study date (e.g., 19940211). These entries are in the YYYYMMDD sequence. How do I compute the difference between these two values in terms of months?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this,

[image]

• Formula used in cell `C2`

```
=INT(YEARFRAC((TEXT(A2,"0000\/00\/00")+0),(TEXT(B2,"0000\/00\/00")+0))*12)
```

---

Or, using `DATEDIF()`

• Formula used in cell `D2`

```
=DATEDIF((TEXT(A2,"0000\/00\/00")+0),(TEXT(B2,"0000\/00\/00")+0),"M")
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert the strings to dates, then substract one from the other. Assuming the two dates are in A1 and B1 you would get something like this:

```
=DATE(LEFT(A1,4),MID(A1,5,2),RIGHT(A1,2))-DATE(LEFT(B1,4),MID(B1,5,2),RIGHT(B1,2))
```

Comment: Considering the birthdate of 19890416 (at A1) and study date of 20000302 (at B1), using your formula, I get 3973 months instead of 132 months.

Comment: No, you get 3973 days, which is approximately 132 months, divide it by 30